# How long does it take for a message from Google Cloud Messaging to arrive on device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How long does it take for a message from Google Cloud Messaging to arrive on a device?

I want to link my door bell with my Android App. The door bell I receive on a RaspberryPi which has an internet connection. I could connect to Google Cloud Messaging, but would the message arrive soon on my Android device?

Comment: The formula is something like this. heartbeat*datarate*SnR(of carrier). So basically it depends upon the carrier or ISP your using and GCM performance at that time. How much priority it gives to your message. Almost 1-8 seconds. Thats what I have tested. TTL(time to live) in network also varies so there's no guarantee that if your device is off, how long GCM would hold your message.

Comment: Time has passed since this was asked and an average speed was mentioned in the I/O 2015. You can refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37385186/4625829) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Almost immediately (1-2sec) if phone is active and has stable internet connection. But there is no 100% guarantee. If phone is sleeping it can take time. If you forgot to pay your carrier bills it will never come.

Comment: it can take up to 5 mins in my experience - usually instant over wifi but 1-5% of the time it can be slower

Answer (score 1):

After months of using in on a production application I've come to notice that it's not so reliable. I've noticed it can take up to 20 minutes to receive a notification. I feel like I was getting much better speed and reliability from sending out an SMS text message.

Yes, it usually comes in a few seconds. But sometimes it can take a while.